# Elixir Phoenix pattern matching "params"

Tags: pattern-matching, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am struggling to understand pattern matching in my specific case; I'm trying to get the values from `params`, which I think is a struct, in a Phoenix controller.

Typing `params` in `iex` results in

```
%{"edit" => "93213e66-a15e-11e6-8bc7-38c986312498",
  "job_slug" => "7759-tkhkjd-test"}
```

However, running the following command:

```
pry(7)> {edit, job_slug} = params
```

throws this error:

```
** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: %{"edit" => "93213e66-a15e-11e6-8bc7-38c986312498", "job_slug" => "7759-tkhkjd-test"}
     (stdlib) :erl_eval.expr/3
```

How do I correctly pattern match against `params`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `params` is a Map but you are matching it against a Tuple. You should try this:

```
%{"edit" => edit, "job_slug" => job_slug} = params
```

---

**From the [Elixir Pattern Matching guide](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/pattern-matching.html):**

> The match operator (=) is not only used to match against simple values, but it is also useful for destructuring more complex data types. [...] A pattern match will error in the case the sides can’t match [...] and also when comparing different types.

This means your LHS and RHS must be of the same type, and must match correctly to assign the variables on the left. In your case you had a Map on your right hand side, and a Tuple on your left hand side, which raised a `MatchError`.

---

**Relevant Links:**

- [Elixir Getting Started - Pattern Matching](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/pattern-matching.html)
- [Elixir: pattern matching works differently for tuples and maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23693173/elixir-pattern-matching-works-differently-for-tuples-and-maps)
- [Pattern match on value of Map's key in elixir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40118252/pattern-match-on-value-of-maps-key-in-elixir/40118333#40118333)

Answer (score 0):

You need to match the struct, not just the inside bits:

%{"edit" => edit, "job_slug" => job_slug} = params

Comment: It's not a struct in this case; it's a map. There's a difference.